# AsyncTask to manage pictures downloaded from Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask, amazon-s3

I have a listView where each row contains a picture (picture can be the same than in other rows), these pictures are downloaded separately from Amazon S3 via an AsyncTask.

The problem is that I don't know how to manage these downloads, because I launch the AsyncTask to get the picture in the adapter for each row (in getView), so my AsyncTask can download multiple time a picture already downloaded.

What I want to know is how can I notify my adapter from my AsyncTask when a picture is downloaded: Broadcast, Handler, Listener, and how can I implement this ?

I think I need to have a map where I put the filename at the beginning of the downloading (so when an other row launch the AsyncTask I can know that the picture is downloading), but how to notify the adapter when the downloading is finish ?

```
public class AmazonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

Context context;
Fragment fragment;

ImageView view;
String picture;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public AmazonAsyncTask(Context context, String picture) {
    this.context = context;
    this.picture = picture;
}

public AmazonAsyncTask(Fragment fragment, String picture) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.picture = picture;
}

public AmazonAsyncTask(Context context, ImageView view, ProgressBar progressBar,
        String picture) {
    this.view = view;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.picture = picture;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    //STORE ON SD CARD
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extr + "/Folder");

    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }

    String strF = mFolder.getAbsolutePath();
    File mSubFolder = new File(strF + "/pictures");

    if (!mSubFolder.exists()) {
        mSubFolder.mkdir();
    }

    if(!"".equals(picture)){
         String s = picture;

         File f = new File(mSubFolder.getAbsolutePath(),s);

         Bitmap bitmap = AppController.getInstance().getBitmapFromMemCache(picture);
         if(bitmap == null){
            String bucketName = "my_bucket_name";
            try {
                S3Object object = AppController.getInstance().getAmazonS3().getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName,"pictures/" + picture));
                InputStream is = object.getObjectContent();                     

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
                is.close();     

                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

                AppController.getInstance().addBitmapToMemoryCache(picture, bitmap);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception ase) {
                return null;
            }
         } else return bitmap;
    } else return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

}
```

Comment: please post your AsyncTask.

Comment: Done in my original question ;-)

Comment: is the adapter calling the Task?

Comment: Yes, in getView I execute this task, but it launch the downloading for each picture (I can handle this with a map to avoid launching same picture downloading) but I don't know how to notify each row using this picture from this AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for downloading images into views. It's a great, simple library which can be used in `getView()` to download images asynchronously and without the need to notify the adapter or anything.

Your `getView()` will be like this:

```
@Override public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
  if (view == null) {
     view = new SquaredImageView(context);
  }
  String url = getItem(position);

  Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);
}
```

**Update:**

As the url is not available for Picasso to download the image, you can use something like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to handle the callback and notifying.

You can define an event with the image inside it to be passed:

```
public class ImageEvent {
   Bitmap bitmap;

   //...
}
```

Register your activity or fragment to the bus and add the handler inside it to store the image to your cache:

```
public class YourActivity {

   //...

   public void onCreate(...) {
      //...
      EventBus.getDefault.register(this);
   }

   //...

   public void onEvent(ImageEvent imgEvent) {
      AppController.getInstance().addBitmapToMemoryCache(picture, imgEvent.getImage());
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

(You can put this handling method in your adapter class)

Now, all that remains is that the class responsible for downloading the image, creates the ImageEvent, put the image inside and post it to EvenBus:

```
ImageEvent imgEvent = new ImageEvent();
imgEvent.setImage(downloadedImage);
EventBus.getDefault.post(imgEvent);
```

EventBus will then call the handler and you have your image inside the cache to be used in any part of your app.

Comment: The problem is that I can't access to my pictures via an url, I download them via the Amazon S3 SDK

Comment: In that case, I think something like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) would be a good solution for you. You can define the downloaded image as an event to be passed to the handler.

Comment: It works like a BroadcastSender I guess or EventBus is a customize Broadcast manager ?

Comment: Technically, it doesn't actually broadcast messages. It's more of a callback manager. You register objects in your app as *handlers* and define the event handler method. When an event of that type is posted to the bus (from any other classes), the handling method is called and the event is passed to it.

Comment: And how can I handle in the method getView in my adapter, these events, can I redeclare onEvent methode in it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private interface BitmapDownloadListener {
          public void onBitmapDownloaded(Bitmap bit);
```

add to the AsyncTask

```
private BitmapDownloadListener mListener;

public void setListener(BitmapDownloadListener listener) {
      mListener = listener;
}
```

add to `onPostExecute(Bitmap result)`

```
if(mListener != null) { onBitmapDownloaded(result); }
```

override the function inside the Adapter now add to the getView..

```
AmazonAsyncTask task = new AmazonAsyncTask();
task.setListener(new BitmapDownloadResponse());
....
....

class BitmapDownloadResponse implements BitmapDownloadListener {

     public void onBitmapDownloaded(Bitmap bit) {

          .......
      }

 }
```

This will create a simple Callback to the Adapter so when your finish the download it will send the overrided function the Bitmap.
you can add variables to the listener for example if you need the position you can send it too..

Comment: This is this kind of functionnality that I needed, but I'm not yet very comfortable with this kind of implementation ;)

But In the adapter, the onBitmapDownloaded function will be implement outside of the getView, so when this function will be called after the picture downloading, how to set the correct ImageView ?

Comment: The problem with that is that I want to notify all "rows" that use the same picture. So, when I launch the download of a picture in the AsyncTask, it will block the downloading of the same picture (ok for this), and once the picture downloaded I want to notify all rows.

Comment: I thought about creating a list in the adapter, I will fill this list at every getView call with the ImageView (with tag = imageId), and when onBitmapDownloaded will be call (outside of the getView), I will search in that list the correct tag, and set the bitmap on found Image View ?